# Is it possible for an Alfresco workflow to be used for "anonymous planning poker"?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We're investigating Alfresco for doing wideband delphi ("planning poker") based on submitted statements of work (collected user stories).   I've been reading through the Alfresco documentation, and there are two questions that I haven't been able to get clear answers to:

- Can we set it up so users can write, but not read, to a folder or node?  (To support "anonymous" planning, without users knowing what the other users submitted estimates were)
- Can workflow tasks be implemented to ask users to comment or submit items to a node or director with the above model, rather than just simple approve or deny?

Workflow:

- User submits a statement of work
- All users (or selected users at random, or ... ) in group get notice to review
- Reviews include estimates on the overall SOW or specific phases
- Reviews are anonymous/secret to all but the manager

Have you implemented something similar in Alfresco with fine grained access control? Sharing your experience would be very helpful... i'm not looking for someone to do the work for me, just to confirm it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

I would use some kind of parallel workflow for this.

First the managers starts the workflow and the task type of this first node will have additional info about the user story and such, then the manager selects a people or a group to which it will send this user story.

Here comes the parallel thing into play. Because it's parallel noone sees the results of the other members of the workflow. The members fill in the requested fields (another custom task type with data like: score (estimate) and maybe explanation.

Before the workflow goes back to manager the automatic calculations are made in a non-user task/node where you calculate overall score for the story. You can include each individual user and their score in the result/report if necessary.

Now the results are sent to the manager.